# How to increase space between text and it's underline in TextView Android?

Tags: android-layout, android

I want to increase space between text and it's underline. I can change line height but I don't change height between text and it's underline.How can I do this ?

```
private static final String FONTH_PATH = "fonts/Brandon_bld.otf";

...

selectTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.selectTextView);
selectTextView.setTypeface(font);

SpannableString content = new SpannableString(getResources().getString(R.string.select_your_prove_type));
content.setSpan(new UnderlineSpan(), 0, content.length(), 0);
selectTextView.setText(content);

...
```

and xml file

```
<TextView
android:id="@+id/selectTextView"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="0dp"
android:layout_weight="536"
android:gravity="left"
android:lineSpacingMultiplier="0.8"
android:text="@string/select_your_prove_type"
android:textColor="@color/Blue"
android:textSize="@dimen/select_size" />
```

Comment: I don't know the answer, maybe linespacingextra attribute should do it but why is your weight attribute has value 536 `android:layout_weight="536"`?

Comment: lineSpacingExtra does not work for this issue. I split the screen according to Iphone psd. Height is 1136 px in this psd and my root layout weightSum is also 1136.

Answer (score 11):

Just use the

> paddingBottom

as follows

```
         <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/fragment_activity_edit_desc"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:paddingBottom="16dp"
                android:hint="Description"
                android:textSize="34sp"
                tools:text="Secret Death Ray Design"/>


        </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

Comment: Did you use it with TextView? I tried and it does not work with TextView @Uzair Mohammad

Answer (score 3):

Add these line in `EditText`

```xml
<EditText
   ...
   android:includeFontPadding="true"
   android:paddingBottom="20dp" />
```

Comment: Does not work with UnderlineSpan or TextView

Answer (score 2):

Okay here's a more complete answer:

In your styles.xml, add a style:

```
<style name="MyTour.HeadingText">
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/tour_header_line_layerlist</item>
</style>
```

Now create a tour_header_line_layerlist.xml file with content:

```
<layer-list
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:top="20dp" android:drawable="@drawable/tour_header_line"/>
</layer-list>
```

The above will set a margin top of 20dp for the line (extract it out to dimen.xml for completeness)

Now create the corresponding tour_header_line.xml:

```
<shape android:shape="line"
   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<stroke
        android:width="1dp"
        android:color="@color/tour_subheading_color" />
```

Now reference the style in your control:

```
    <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:text="@string/tour_1_heading_text"
            android:id="@+id/heading_text" android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            style="@style/MyTour.HeadingText" //notice this
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin_large"/>
```

Let me know if you have other questions!

Comment: This is working great with android:top="20dp", Why it's not working when we change top value?

Comment: Works if you are just underlining an entire TextView, but won't work on individual lines or sections of lines and doesn't address OP's UnderlineSpan issue

Answer (score -1):

You can add the custom underline with a drawable file (in my case I've created a shadow) and set this custom underline with

```
android:background="@drawable/shadow_file.xml"
```

After that with adding padding to your EditText you can add more space between the line and the text.

```
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/underline_space"
```

and define this dimension on your dimens.xml file.

That works for me, and I hope for you too :)

Comment: Thank you for sharing your answer but I couldn't understand. Did you create a custom edittext ? @jgarciabt

Comment: Sorry for my short explanation. I've got a default EditText but with a custom underline. You can add the custom underline with a drawable file (in my case I've created a shadow) and with android:background="@drawable/shadow_file.xml" set this custom underline. After that with the padding you can add more space between the line and the text.

Comment: can you please share shadow_file.xml or explain how to add it?

Comment: if you share `shadow_file.xml`, it would be more clear.